# Can't call a model method in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im pretty new to ruby-on-rails and hope you can help me. I am trying to write a plugin for Redmine using ruby-on-rails. And I'm having some problems calling a new method from my model in my controller. So I made the Redmine plugin tutorial and had these items afterwards:

Model:

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  def vote(answer)
     increment(answer == 'yes' ? :yes : :no)
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class PollsController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
     @polls = Poll.all
  end

  def vote
    poll = Poll.find(params[:id])
    poll.vote(params[:answer])
    if poll.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Vote saved.'
    end
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  end
end
```

index.html:

```
<h2>Polls</h2>

<% @polls.each do |poll| %>
  <p>
  <%= poll.question %>?
  <%= link_to 'Yes', { :action => 'vote', :id => poll[:id], :answer => 'yes' }, :method => :post %> (<%= poll.yes %>) /
  <%= link_to 'No', { :action => 'vote', :id => poll[:id], :answer => 'no' }, :method => :post %> (<%= poll.no %>)
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Afterwards I wanted to add Wikicontent to the same html just to get used to work with RoR. So my present items look like these:

Model:

```
    class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  def vote(answer)
     increment(answer == 'yes' ? :yes : :no)
  end
  def self.load_content
      @wiki_content = Poll.find_by_sql ("select wc.text
                                 , wc.comments
                                 , wc.version
                                from wiki_contents wc 
                                where wc.page_id = (select min(id) 
                                      from wiki_pages
                                      where wiki_id = 3")
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class PollsController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
     @polls = Poll.all
     @wiki_content = Poll.load_content
  end

  def vote
    poll = Poll.find(params[:id])
    poll.vote(params[:answer])
    if poll.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Vote saved.'
    end
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  end
end
```

index.html:

```
<h2>Polls</h2>

<% @polls.each do |poll| %>
  <p>
  <%= poll.question %>?
  <%= link_to 'Yes', { :action => 'vote', :id => poll[:id], :answer => 'yes' }, :method => :post %> (<%= poll.yes %>) /
  <%= link_to 'No', { :action => 'vote', :id => poll[:id], :answer => 'no' }, :method => :post %> (<%= poll.no %>)
  </p>
<% end %>

<% @content.each do |cn| %>
    <p>
        <%= cn.text %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Im getting an "internal error" according to my Browser. I tried to find the error and it seems I can't call the new method from my model inside the controller and i can't figure out why. Like I said I'm really new to RoR so I hope you can help me.

This is the error description in the logfile:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7: select wc.text
                                 , wc.comments
                                 , wc.version
                                from wiki_contents wc 
                                where wc.page_id = (select min(id) 
                                      from wiki_pages
                                      where wiki_id = 3):
```

Best Regards
Arty

Comment: can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: "Internal error

An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance.

If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error."

Comment: I mean your error logs, not the generic 5xx that your browser /web server is showing. The error about the new method (I am guessing you are trying to call something on nil)

Comment: @Arty, can you post the log file from the Rails Server - that'd probably help narrow down where the real issue is.

Comment: Done that and also tried the same SQL Statement from Workbench and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `index.html` you are using `<% @content.each do |cn| %>`, but nowhere in your code snippets you are assigning any values to `@content`.  Since you are assigning `@wiki_content` in your controller `index` action, I'm assuming you want to use `@wiki_content` here:

```
# app/views/polls/index.html
...
<% @wiki_content.each do |cn| %>
    <p>
        <%= cn.text %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

**Update:**

By the error you've posted and a double look at your query you have a syntax error in your query.  You are missing closing parenthesis `)` in your inner select.  Update your query as follows:

```
# app/model/poll.rb
def self.load_content
      @wiki_content = Poll.find_by_sql ("select wc.text
                                 , wc.comments
                                 , wc.version
                                from wiki_contents wc 
                                where wc.page_id = (select min(id) 
                                      from wiki_pages
                                      where wiki_id = 3)")
end
```

Comment: Yeah you're right. Just saw it myself as well, fixed it but the error still appears.

Comment: @Arty, please post the content of the log file when you see this error so that it will be quicker to spot the problem.  Please update your question with the log.

Comment: Done that and also tried the same SQL Statement from Workbench and it works.

Comment: @Arty, please see my update.  You are missing closing parenthesis in your SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to return something in your model method instead of assigning a value to `@wiki_content` as the model does not have any visibility on that variable

it would look like that

```
def self.load_content
      return Poll.find_by_sql ("select wc.text
                                 , wc.comments
                                 , wc.version
                                from wiki_contents wc 
                                where wc.page_id = (select min(id) 
                                      from wiki_pages
                                      where wiki_id = 3")
  end
```

Comment: @amine: The value of the last executed statement will be returned automatically in ruby. You don't have to explicitly return it.

Comment: that's right. the essential part is to drop the `@wiki_content =`